# JavaScript function within loop / closure

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to understand the behavior of this code, which attempts to assign unique `onclick` handlers to different DOM elements in the array `myElements[]`:

```
(function handleClicks(){
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
myElements[i].onclick = function() {
        alert( 'You clicked on: ' + i );
};
})();
```

My understanding is that each time a DOM element is clicked, the browser should alert 'You clicked on 100' as JavaScript will use the value `i` has once the function has completed

I have two questions:

1. If `i` only has scope within the function `handleClicks()` how can the browser access `i` once the function has completed - surely `i` no longer exists?
2. I tried this code by putting two HTML elements in the array

   ```
   var myElements = [];
   myElements.push( document.getElementById('1');
   myElements.push( document.getElementById('2');
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/branmong/fS7qE/

But when the program runs, it alerts 'you clicked on: 2' for each element clicked.

Why isn't it alerting 'you clicked on: 100'. as this is surely the value of `i` once the function has finished running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"If `i` only has scope within the function `handleClicks()` how can the browser access `i` once the function has completed - surely `i` no longer exists?"*

The `i` variable is in the enclosing scope *(the `handleClicks` function)*. When a function is created, it carries with it its original variable scope for the life of the function. This is called *closure*.

Because of this, all the handler functions created in the loop are referencing the same `i` variable that exists in `handleClicks`. This keeps `i` alive. When you destroy the handlers, `i` will be able to be garbage collected.

---

The second code example stops at `2` because you get a *TypeError* for accessing a property on `undefined`. This halts the execution of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have only two elements in the myElements array. So, the loop executes only uptil 2 and errors out after that. If you added 5 elements it would show 5, show 100 if you added 100.